# Volvo D13 Boost and fuel mileage problem

Tags: diesel, volvo, turbocharger

My Volvo diesel D13 creates boost at low RPM's at various amounts of level and at any given time; the fuel mileage has gone down by 1.5 miles per gallon. The waste gate was replaced and the computer was reprogrammed twice with no improvement. 
Help please!

Comment: Thanks for being here! We like to see new people ... can you please clarify exactly what your question is, though? Are you looking for the fix or are you just sore that your fuel mileage is down? I'm not sure how to take this ;-) Do you have *any other information*?

Comment: To add to what @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 is saying.  Is there anything else you can add regarding information and what the issue is.  Is it the mileage?  You don't have a question that is implicitly asked so it leaves things to assumption.  Also, can you add the year of the vehicle into your post?

Comment: When you say your computer was reprogrammed do you mean it was done at a dealer? or was tuned?

Comment: Is it boosting sooner than it did before?  A drop is gas mileage could be related to MANY things.  What makes you think the boost is responsible?

Comment: It is a 2008 Volvo D13 and the reprogramming was done a second time at a dealership because another dealership ha reprogrammed it after replacing the head on it and the second dealership did the programming again as a desperation move to see if it was causing the problem.

Comment: The issue is that ever since the truck has had the major repairs, it has been running strangely and mileage has gone down from over 9 mpg to 7.5 for the last months since the repairs. The engine will show turbo boost fluctuations even at idle and the repair shops are at a loss for  trying to find out what the problem is. The last time they told us to bring it in because they got a response from Volvo that it could be the intake manifold sensor that causes this but after replacing it there was no change. Note also that both Volvo repair shops tested the turbo with the same conclusion; it's fine

Comment: I only have one thing to say. Our 2015 d13 gets us an average of 6.8 to 7.3 miles to the gal averaged over a 1 mth running period. We team drive from Alberta to Texas. 15 to 17000 miles a mth. Our loads average is about, total gross of about 78500 lbs. 745000 kim 1set of injectors. What else can be said. Normal wear and tear factors. Regular maintainous schedules. It's a great little truck. Thanks Ron